# jQuery setTimeout in loop of each

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I am new to jQuery. I have number of divs which I want to fade in 1 by 1 in an endless loop. To fadein I am using CSS animation on class `active`; here is what I tried, but this only work once.

HTML

```
<div id="bgContainer">
    <div class="slides"> <img src=".." /> </div>
    <div class="slides"> <img src=".." /> </div>
    <div class="slides"> <img src=".." /> </div>
    <div class="slides"> <img src=".." /> </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#bgContainer div').each(function(i) {
var currentSlide = $(this);
currentSlide.removeClass('active');
i = i + 1;
var intervel = i * 1000;
setTimeout(function () { SliderBG(currentSlide); }, intervel);    
});

function SliderBG(currentSlide) {
    currentSlide.addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Personally I would make this a recursive call to a function, giving it the array of elements it should loop over, and the next index to process.  The method would perform it's work and at the end call a setTimeout to itself a second later, providing the array and next index to process, resetting the index to zero when it reaches the end of the array.

Comment: because you have applied a unique class to every div. you need to change name of class.

Comment: @Taplar friend can u explain with some codes please?

Comment: @kamranshah I posted a solution below using a recursive timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function(){
  //get all the slides
  var $slides = $('#bgContainer div');
  //initialize the index to the first slide
  var index = 0;
  
  //start the loop
  setTimeout(sliderBG, 1000);
  
  function sliderBG () {
    //remove active from all the elements
    $slides.removeClass('active');
    //put it on the next index
    $slides.eq(index).addClass('active');
    //increment the index, reset to 0 at the end
    index = ++index % $slides.length;
    //continue loop after a second
    setTimeout(sliderBG, 1000);
  }
}());
```

```css
.slides {
  background-color: #888;
}

.slides.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bgContainer">
  <div class="slides">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="slides">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="slides">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="slides">Slide 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want, It will loop over each element and add the `.active` class and when it gets to the end it will start over.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  Timer();
});

function Timer(){
var slides = $('#bgContainer .slides'),
    counter = 0,
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      SliderBG(slides[counter]);
      counter++
      if (counter === slides.length) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        Timer()
      }
    }, 1000);
}

function SliderBG(currentSlide) {
  $('#bgContainer .slides.active').add(currentSlide).toggleClass('active');
}
```

```css
.slides {
  display: none;
}

.slides.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bgContainer">
  <div class="slides"> <img src=".." alt="1"/> </div>
  <div class="slides"> <img src=".." alt="2"/> </div>
  <div class="slides"> <img src=".." alt="3"/> </div>
  <div class="slides"> <img src=".." alt="4"/> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: friend I tried your code but it adds the class `active` to each div while the previous div still contains that class .. at times all divs are having `active` and other times non of them having `active`